# How to run mapreduce program on large number of files simultaneously?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on large data sets and run Mapreduce program on it. I can easily run Mapreduce on single file, whose size around 3 GB. know I want to run mapreduce on all files. Is there any shortcut or technique to run mapreduce on all files directly.
Using OS-Ubuntu
Hadoop-2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the files available, specify directory/regular expression in map-reduce input parameter in place of file name.

**Example:**
bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount **/user/joe/wordcount/*.txt** /user/joe/wordcount/output

If you are getting file continuously and want process as and when they arrive.
you have to run map-reduce job again and again. because it is batch job.